# what is wrong in my dockerfile it does not copy my s3 bucket file

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu 
ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxx
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxx/8fMox8eNWTY51
ENV AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-2
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y awscli

ADD main.sh /main.sh
RUN chmod +x /main.sh
RUN /main.sh


#!/bin/bash



 docker login --username=xxx--password=12xxxx
 docker pull mariadb
 docker pull mysql


 # you can also write the credentials into the awscli configuration file. 
aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY 
aws configure set AWS_DEFAULT_REGION $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION


aws s3 cp s3://mariadbs3bucket/test4.txt /test 

 mysql -u sathish  -pxx --host testmariadb.ci9m4obirg2u.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306  --socket=TCP/IP  -e "USE myDB; insert into myDB.TestTable values(50000);"
```

My s3 cp commnad is not working 
and Mysql command is not working its giving error . is there any mistake in my docker file . or docker does not identify my env variable ? 
can you please help me

Comment: My main.sh start from #bin

Comment: can you share main.sh

Comment: can you share the eror message as well? It's hard to find out a solution without a hint of what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add RUN command before aws
like 
RUN aws cp

Comment: `RUN` is not a bash command. His shell script starts from the shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) as he had explained in a comment well before you've posted your answer.